# plot multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am Building a GUI by Python and want to plot the the daily bonus of employees depends on the user plotting target:

```
Bob=[100,30,50,90]
Sammy=[10,60,90,200] 
Tom=[70,90,90,90]

# input from GUI User is Tom
ploting_target='Tom'

if ploting_target=='Tom':`
   plt.plot([0,1,2,3], Tom)

elif ploting_target=='Sammy':
   plt.plot([0,1,2,3], Sammy)

plt.plot([0,1,2,3], Tom)

____________________________________________
#expecting  
#find_target=list_of_employee.index(ploting_target)

#plt(plot([0,1,2,3], list_of_employee[find_target])
```

Comment: What is your specific coding question? You might want to organize your data as a dictionary e.g.: `plotting_dict = dict(Bob=[100,30,50,90], Sammy=[10,60,90,200],Tom=[70,90,90,90])` and `plt.plot([0,1,2,3], plotting_dict[ploting_target])`

Comment: thanks for you comment, i want just to plot the daily bounce that the user want to plot, for example: the input is to Tom ( the bounce is saved as a list in python worksapce) Tom=[70,90,90,90]. so, what i need to write a code to plot these values that is all.

Comment: As per one of the duplicates, the simplest answer, w/o resorting to pandas, is `plt.plot(Bob, 'g', Sammy, 'r', Tom, 'b')`.  And the other duplicate has the pandas approach: `pd.DataFrame([Bob, Sammy, Tom]).T.plot()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear. If you have a list of employees, you can probably use `Pandas` to organize your data (almost the same as @JohanC suggested with `dict`):

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Bob = [100, 30, 50, 90]
Sammy = [10, 60, 90, 200] 
Tom = [70, 90, 90, 90]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Bob': Bob, 'Sammy': Sammy, 'Tom': Tom})
df.index = 'Date ' + df.index.astype(str)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Bob  Sammy  Tom
Day 0  100     10   70
Day 1   30     60   90
Day 2   50     90   90
Day 3   90    200   90
```

Now you can do `df.plot()`:

[image]

Or for a specific employee `df['Sammy'].plot()`:

[image]

Or for a list of employees (but not all) `df[['Bob', 'Tom']].plot()`:

[image]